# Elasticbeanstalk - Force HTTPs on Docker container with Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single-container Docker running a React environment on Elasticbeanstalk with Nginx. I pointed a subdomain to the ELB URL, and want to force a HTTPS redirection if you visit the subdomain (i.e. you type subdomain.domain.com and it should redirect you to HTTPS).

Now, if I visit the default ELB URL (**something.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com**), it will be redirected to HTTPS. But I want my **custom domain** (which is parked somewhere else but points to something.eu-centralblabla with a CNAME) **to be forced to use HTTPS** as well, but it doesn't happen. It allows regular HTTP requests.

I've tried several guides and followed AWS documentation, but I cannot seem to force it to redirect to HTTPS on my custom subdomain.

These are my files:

**/.ebextensions folder**

## http-instance.config

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  # HTTPS Server

  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://docker;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
#SSL CRT and KEY below
```

## https-instance-single.config

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Properties:
  GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
  IpProtocol: tcp
  ToPort: 443
  FromPort: 443
  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

**/nginx folder**

## default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  error_page 500 504 /500.html;
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  error_page 503 /503.html;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  location ~ ^/(favicon|static)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    # add_header Last-Modified "";
    # add_header ETag "";

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=500s;
    open_file_cache_valid 600s;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    break;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage this in your nginx config by adding this within the server context:

```
set $redirect_to_https 0;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    set $redirect_to_https 1;
}

if ($redirect_to_https = 1) {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Route all http traffic to https:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Then hangle the proxy stuff in the 443 block